# Make git tell whether code contained in two different branches are identical

Tags: git

Does a git command exist to identify whether two branches currently have the exact same code?

I've tried:

```
git diff master develop
```

This command doesn't fail but it doesn't actually do anything either (i.e. it returns nothing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning nothing means they are identical. Just so that you can see for yourself if that's indeed the case, take a look at the tree object ID of the two revisions:

```
git cat-file -p master
git cat-file -p develop
```

They should have the same ID and that means the "tree" (files, directories and content) is the same.